# JQuery count nodes depth difference between 2 elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

there is an easy way to count the nodes depth difference between 2 elements?

Exemple :

```
<div id="1">
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3">
    <div id="4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="5"></div>
```

I would like somethings like :

```
diff($("#1"), $("#2")); //output 1
diff($("#1"), $("#5")); //output 0
diff($("#2"), $("#4")); //output 1
diff($("#1"), $("#4")); //output 2
```

I think there is something to do with parents(), children() function, but i don't know...

Comment: what is "nodes differents/difference"? Explain how you get to your example numbers.

Comment: Why `#1` and `#5` = 0; but `#2` and `#4` = 1

Comment: each time you go inside in an element, you increment a counter by 1. So for #2 and #4, you start at node #2 with a counter = 0, you need to go inside #3 to get #4, so you increase counter by 1. I don't know how to explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your example correctly - all you need to do is count parents of nodes:

```js
diff($("#1"), $("#2"));
diff($("#1"), $("#5"));
diff($("#2"), $("#4"));
diff($("#1"), $("#4"));

function diff(a, b) {
  $('#output').append(
    a.attr('id') + ' and ' + b.attr('id') + ' = ' +
    Math.abs(a.parents().length - b.parents().length)
    + '<br/>'
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="1">
  <div id="2"></div>
  <div id="3">
    <div id="4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="5"></div>
<hr/>
<div id="output"></div>
```